# prevent JSESSIONID to store in cookie

Tags: session, tomcat, gwt, jsessionid

I'm currently working on a project which is built on GWT and deployed on tomcat. The problem is when we tried to access the webpage it stores the `JSESSIONID` into cookies. Now one user is copying that value and share it with other user.
[image: chrome dev tool]

The other user on the other machine installed the `headerMod` extension available for `chrome` and add that `JSESSIONID`. After adding it when user hit the URL, the application redirect the user directly on dashboard instead of login page.

I've tired to add the following config in `web.xml` and now `JSESSIONID` is no more visible. But now the application is logout instantly after login and showing the popup. **Login session expired. You have to login again.**

```
    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

I've a very little knowledge about the session handling in GWT. I wanted to somehow hide this `JSESSIONID` in cookies so that no one can copy. Or there is any better alternative for this. Please guide.

Comment: GWT does not do session handling.  That is done by Tomcat, cookies and the browser.

Answer (score 3):

If a user goes through the hassle of extracting their JSESSIONID cookie and sharing it with others, then complain about those others impersonating them: Revoke their account - this is just one step shy of sharing their credentials, then complaining that someone else logs in as them.

What you can do is to make sure that you're only ever delivering all kind of content, including the cookie, through https. Use HSTS. Disallow unencrypted http.

Some of the state needs to be shared between browser and server - and JSESSIONID is the placeholder for it. Any other technique would also suffer from the same problem: If somebody gets hold of it, they can mimic the other user.

You're chasing a non-problem here.